# CSS variables using lesscss

Tags: css, less

I was reading [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#-variables) and I am wondering why:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;
@light-blue: @nice-blue + #111;
#header { color: @light-blue; }
```

compiles the following output

```
#header { color: #6c94be; }
```

and not

```
#header { color: #6c93ad; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because #111 is short for #111111 and explains exactly what you see here